# How can I remove Cinnamon panel without being able to right click on it?

Tags: panel, cinnamon

I wanted to move my bottom panel on my main monitor to the side, but I can't right click in the empty space and anywhere else I right click just gives me a menu for the specific thing that runs in the panel. I created a left panel on the same monitor and now I can't right click it at all and therefore can't delete it. I can right click and delete panels on my second monitor. However when I set my second monitor as my primary display and right click on the bottom panel from my main monitor, I can delete it, but still not the side panel. How can I get rid of this new side panel?

Comment: Please provide OS & release, you mention only a desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I fixed it by setting my second monitor above my main monitor. No idea how this worked but it did.